# How to find out if the fetched remote reference has newer version of a file?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I have changes to a file (RemoteTest.txt) pushed from *HostA* to the remote. On *HostB* I have the status without that last push.

Now when I go to the bash with "git diff" I see the changes.

```
$ git diff origin/master head
 diff --git a/RemoteTest.txt b/RemoteTest.txt
 index 40604b4..b36b5e8 100644
 --- a/RemoteTest.txt
 +++ b/RemoteTest.txt @@ -1 +1,6 @@
```

..and so on...

I tried to get the changes in C# with

```
IEnumerable<string> paths = new List<string>() {@"origin/master", "head"};
TreeChanges tc = repo.Diff.Compare(paths);
```

But tc shows 0 changes. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to compare the `Tree`s of the `Commit`s pointed at by the `HEAD` and `origin/master` references.

How about something like the following?

```
var headTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
var remoteMasterTree = repo.Branches["origin/master"].Tip.Tree;

TreeChanges tc = repo.Diff.Compare(remoteMasterTree, headTree);
```

**Note:** The optional list of paths the `Compare` overloads accept should contain paths (or pathspecs) to files within the compared `Trees`. For instance, considering your use case, you may pass `new[] { "RemoteTest.txt" }` as a third parameter to the method.